# Disabling ngrok authentication

Tags: authentication, ngrok

This question might be stupid, but I'm a beginner and I can't disable authentication on ngrok. I was having problems with CORS PUTs so, following this https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/196, I decided to use "disable_options_auth" but I can't seem to figure out how. I tried this on the configuration file:

```
tunnels:
  demo:
    proto: http
    addr: 8080
    inspect: false
    auth: disable_options_auth
```

Answer (score -1):

The linked GitHub issue mentions that ngrok *didn't* alter its config file `auth` parameter to accept a value of `disable_options_auth`:

> ... if this [accepting CORS preflight requests without auth while enforcing auth on all other requests] is the behavior you want, that you should implement the authentication yourself in your application.

If you just want to disable auth entirely that should make CORS preflight requests work, and you can do that by simply removing the `auth` parameter from your config altogether.